# Select .app Files in MacOS File Browser using C#/DotNet

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, chromium

I'm working on a MacOS application built in Unity3D.  I'm using a [native file browser plugin](https://github.com/gkngkc/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser) to open native MacOS file dialogs for selecting files.
In order to generate PDFs, my app relies on using Chromium's Headless/command line functionality.

On Windows, I can easily get the path to the included Microsoft Edge as that's standard, but on Mac, unless I guess and check (which I already do), there isn't a way to guarantee a Mac user has a Chromium-based browser installed.

So I intend on allowing the user to set the path manually by selecting the `.app` file with a file dialog.  But even when I specify `.app` to be a valid extension, they still don't appear selectable.

I assume this is some sort of MacOS-specific limitation or default permissions, though I can't find much info on this online.

Using C#/DotNet s there any way of allowing this behavior as needed?

For some more info:  I'm just running the application using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` with command line arguments.
Based on my experiments searching for Google Chrome (though Edge or Opera are just as usable), the path I'm looking for is:
`/Applications/ {{APP NAME}}.app/Contents/MacOS/{{APP NAME}}`
Because `Contents` isn't accessible by most users, I figured I would just automatically go in and grab the binary with the correct name.

I know I could include some lightweight version of ChromeDriver with my app, but I'd rather keep everything as self-contained as possible, especially as so many people already have Chrome (or Opera, Edge, etc) installed.  The challenge is that not everyone has it installed in the same place, hence my need to make it customizable.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing:  It seems that this limitation is only when running inside the Unity Editor.  Once the app is built into a standalone Mac application, the file dialog does allow the selection of .app files and it works as expected.

Not a 100% solution to this problem, but definitely clears up some concerns.